# error while using elastic search while creating a osgi bundle

Tags: java, elasticsearch, osgi-bundle

created a wrapper for elastic search. it working fine while running as java application.
But while i create OSGI bundle it throwing a error.

```
  org.elasticsearch.env.FailedToResolveConfigException: Failed to resolve config path [names.txt], tried file path [names.txt], path file [/home/local/PAYODA/sidharthan.r/config/names.txt], and classpath
at org.elasticsearch.env.Environment.resolveConfig(Environment.java:207)
at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:118)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:154)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:120)
at com.payoda.commons.elasticsearch.util.GenericEsSearch.getES(GenericEsSearch.java:54)
```

Pls help me..
am using ES version 0.90.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place names.txt file inside bundle.you can find names.txt file inside elasticsearch.jar.Add following code where you create client instance.

```
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(*classname*.class.getClassLoader());
        Builder settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", esHosts);
        settings.put("path.conf", path_of_names.txt);
        TransportClient transportClient = new TransportClient(settings);
```

I added 2 jars to my class_path, they are elasticsearch.jar,lucene.jar. Version of jars must be same as version of Elasticsearch.

now it works like charm..

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the implementation of `Environment.resolveConfig()` (the one that throws the Exception), it uses `settings.getClassLoader().getResource(path)` to resolve files. The default is to use `Classes.getDefaultClassLoader()` which uses `Thread.getContextClassLoader()`. As 'names.txt' is inside elasticsearch*.jar, any ClassLoader from an org.elasticsearch.* class will do:

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
  .classLoader(Settings.class.getClassLoader())
  // snip: add some settings
  .build();
```

Alternatively, you can place your own names.txt file either in the current working directory or in your config directory ('path.conf' setting or $home/config by default, $home being the value of 'path.home' setting or 'user.dir' system property by default).

Btw, I've done some experimenting with elasticsearch and OSGI myself, so maybe [molindo-elasticsync](https://github.com/molindo/molindo-elasticsync) is of help. Additionally, there are [elasticsearch bundles provided by Servicemix](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/servicemix/smx4/bundles/trunk/elasticsearch-0.90.5) that might be helpful.